# Swift 3 getting nil value in firebase while retrieving data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as my backend i am trying to get the name from firebase of users and trying to display it in `UITableView` but i am not getting it in `UITableView`.
My code :-

```
 func retriveData() {
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshot {
                if let userDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                    print("user dict - \(String(describing: userDict["name"]))")
                    let username = userDict["name"] as? String
                    self.uname.append(username!)
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

My JSON:-

[image: json]

I have used uname array of strings and used it in `UITableView` delegate methods.

Comment: what is userDict printing??

Comment: @User511 user dict - Optional(assessing),user dict - Optional(Yash)

Comment: So you are able to append username in name array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reload your table view after appending the data to array:**

```
func retriveData() {
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            for snap in snapshot {
                if let userDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                    print("user dict - \(String(describing: userDict["name"]))")
                    let username = userDict["name"] as? String
                    self.uname.append(username!)
                }
            }
                tableView.reloadData()

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to reload the data on the main queue?

Comment: No it will also work.